# How to have different network-security-config for different build variants?

Tags: android, certificate, ssl-certificate, android-7.0-nougat

I would like to trust certificate only in one build-variant. How to make it?

Comment: Do you have a different network security configuration that you want to use in other build variants? Or do you only want network security configuration at all in this one variant?

Comment: I only want security configuration at in this one variant.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Create a source for the variant. Create a `res/xml/` directory in that source set, and put your network security configuration XML in there. Create other stuff in that source set as needed (e.g., `res/raw/` and your certificate). In that source set, create an `AndroidManifest.xml` file, with an `<application>` element that just has the `android:networkSecurityConfig` attribute and nothing else.

And you should be done.

Builds for this variant will include your source set, merge in the `android:networkSecurityConfig` attribute, and leverage the resources tied to it. Builds for other variants will ignore this source set, leaving you without a network security configuration.

Comment: To add on to this, the `AndroidManifest.xml` file is not actually required for each build variant. If your network-security-config file is in the appropriate folder structure as suggested (for example: `/app/src/debug/res/xml/network_security_config.xml`), then the app will automatically use and apply it.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Should the AndroidManifest.xml just contain

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.xxx">

    <application
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
    </application>
</manifest>

Comment: @Prashanth That should be sufficient. I do not recall if you need the `package` attribute or not (since that will be supplied by the merger process).

Comment: @CommonsWare - Thank you!!

I can just have network_security_config.xml in my main/res/src/xml and my main main AndroidManifest.xml need not contain android:networkSecurityConfig in application tag ?

Just let me know if this is right.
Thanks

Comment: @Prashanth: The question asked here is specifically for *not* putting these things in `main`, but instead have it be for a particular build variant.

Answer (score -1):

Just create 'n' number of customized network security XML for your 'n' number of build variant, and then you can inject exact network security XML file to your Android Manifest XML depend on the Environment. see here for examples https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables

Answer (score -1):

You can create build_variant folder inside src and your network_config file inside that

below is some sample for different icon for different build_variant. same way we can do for network_config file

***/src/build_variant/res/xml/network_security_config.xml***

[image: Exmaple]